# how to loop down and replace value of next row with specific value in a column

Tags: python

I am reformatting an excel file with a script and here is the data set I am working with

```
   Month Amount Location
0  Month $$$    LocationA
1  Month $$$    str
2  Month $$$    str
3  Month $$$    str
4  Nan   nan    LocationSummary
5  Month $$$    str
6  Month $$$    str
7  Month $$$    str
8  Month $$$    str
9  Month nan    LocationB
10 Month $$$    str
11 Month $$$    str
12 Month $$$    str
13 Month $$$    str
14 Month nan    LocationSummary
:
:
```

my target is to have a fresh data set like this

```
  Month Amount Location
0 Month $$$    LocationA
1 Month $$$    LocationA
2 Month $$$    LocationA
3 Month $$$    LocationB
4 Month $$$    LocationB
5 Month $$$    LocationB
6 Month $$$    LocationB
:
:
```

as you can see, I am trying to clean out column `Location` by getting rid of location summary range and replace str with the closet location name.
I am thinking about looping down the column like this:

```
for x in column location:
    if x==str:
       x=x-1
    else:
       x 
    end
df=df[~df.location.str.contains("summary")]
```

I could never get the for loop to work because how to write correctly to iterate string.
I get error like:

```
'TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str'
```

or incorrect syntax

Comment: Please provide a MCVE. See: [mcve]. Have you read the Pandas docs? You cannot expect people to do all the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

'TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str'. This is a type casting error. you must convert that string into an integer in order to do the x - 1 operation.

So, I believe your error is in the line

```
x = x - 1
```

because if x is a string you can't do that operation. try with

```
x = str(int(x) - 1)
```

let me explain how it works because I think you are not very familiar with Python

with the int() function we convert the string to an integer. For example if x = '2' with int(x) we will have the integer value, not the string value. And with the str() function we will convert that integer value into a string again.

This is what I mean:

```
a = int('2') #Then a will be equal to the integer 2
b = str(2) #Then b will be equal to the string '2'
```